# angular cli build put static files in root of /dist for given project

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

Hi I have some static files that I need copied to the root of the apps dist dir (not in myapp/dist/assets)  Is there way to configure the angular.json file to do this during a ng build?

angular v 6.0.3

Comment: You can easily do it with a custom script which you can run after `ng build`. I don't think that `ng` has an option for this.

Comment: Add them to the root of the project, and define them as assets within `angular.json`, just like `favicon.ico` is by default. No need for a script

Comment: favicon does not end up in the dist root - It ends up in the root of whatever language folder you have.

Ie dist only contains folders 'en' and 'de' where favicon will be in the root of both folders but there are no default files in the dist root! ng12.
If you only have one language then yes, placing it in angular.json works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add script commands inside package.json.

```
scripts: {
"copyAssets": "cp -r src/assets/* dist/assets/ || copy /Y src/assets/* dist/assets/ ",
}
```

You can include 'npm run copyAssets' in the build script.

Comment: Still valid for ng12 - Thanks